# Portable class library with project.json no longer builds in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Portable class library targeting Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 using project.json (created according to https://oren.codes/2016/02/08/project-json-all-the-things/).

The project json looks like this

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.3"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    ".NETPortable,Version=v4.6,Profile=Profile32": {}
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win": {},
    "win-anycpu": {},
    "win-x86": {},
    "win-x64": {},
    "win-arm": {}
  }
}
```

When I try to build it in VS2015 Update 2 I get

> Your project.json doesn't list 'win' as a targeted runtime. You should add '"win": { }' inside your "runtimes" section in your project.json, and then re-run NuGet restore.

As you can see, `win` is contained in project.json.

Here is a minimal solution to reproduce the problem: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73642/ClassLibrary1.zip

Comment: In cases like this (e.g. moving sources to another machine) I often have to remove the local `packages` folder, then NuGet will restore it, and suddenly the project builds again. Not sure if it will help in this case, but worth trying, esp. because `re-run NuGet restore` is shown in the error.

Comment: there is no packages folder with project.json and the project was not moved

Comment: ok... then I don't know.

Comment: Igor, any luck with this? Would be interested to hear if you've made progress.

Comment: No progress, also reported it to Connect, no reaction as usuall